# 'tee' and exit status

Tags: unix, shell, tee

Is there an alternative to [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) which captures [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) of the command being executed and exits with the same exit status as the processed command?

Something like the following:

```
eet -a some.log -- mycommand --foo --bar
```

Where "eet" is an imaginary alternative to "tee" :) (*-a* means append and `--` separates the captured command). It shouldn't be hard to hack such a command, but maybe it already exists and I'm not aware of it?

Comment: I assume that the real question here is: how to tee output AND capture exit status. If so: possible duplicate of [bash: tee output AND capture exit status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221833/bash-tee-output-and-capture-exit-status)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an `eet`.  Works with every Bash I can get my hands on, from 2.05b to 4.0.

```
#!/bin/bash
tee_args=()
while [[ $# > 0 && $1 != -- ]]; do
    tee_args=("${tee_args[@]}" "$1")
    shift
done
shift
# now ${tee_args[*]} has the arguments before --,
# and $* has the arguments after --

# redirect standard out through a pipe to tee
exec | tee "${tee_args[@]}"

# do the *real* exec of the desired program
exec "$@"
```

(`pipefail` and `$PIPESTATUS` are nice, but I recall them being introduced in 3.1 or thereabouts.)

Comment: It's strange - but it doesn't work for me:

  jirka@debian:~/monitor$ exec | wc -c \\
  0 \\
  jirka@debian:~/monitor$ exec echo a \\
  a

(\\ means newline)

Answer (score 36):

This works with Bash:

```
(
  set -o pipefail
  mycommand --foo --bar | tee some.log
)
```

The parentheses are there to limit the effect of pipefail to just the one command.

From the [*bash(1)* man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> The return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command, unless the `pipefail` option is enabled.  If `pipefail` is enabled, the pipeline's return status is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands exit successfully.

Answer (score 11):

I stumbled upon a couple of interesting solutions at *[Capture Exit Code Using Pipe & Tee](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=597613)*.

1. There is the $PIPESTATUS variable available in Bash:

   ```
   false | tee /dev/null
   [ $PIPESTATUS -eq 0 ] || exit $PIPESTATUS
   ```
2. And the simplest prototype of "eet" in Perl may look as follows:

   ```perl
   open MAKE, "command 2>&1 |" or die;
   open (LOGFILE, ">>some.log") or die;
   while (<MAKE>) { 
       print LOGFILE $_; 
       print 
   }
   close MAKE; # To get $?
   my $exit = $? >> 8;
   close LOGFILE;
   ```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I consider to be the best pure-Bourne-shell solution to use as the base upon which you could build your "eet":

```
# You want to pipe command1 through command2:
exec 4>&1
exitstatus=`{ { command1; echo $? 1>&3; } | command2 1>&4; } 3>&1`
# $exitstatus now has command1's exit status.
```

I think this is best explained from the inside out – `command1` will execute and print its regular output on stdout (file descriptor 1), then once it's done, `echo` will execute and print `command1`'s exit code on its stdout, but that stdout is redirected to file descriptor three.

While `command1` is running, its stdout is being piped to command2 (`echo`'s output never makes it to command2 because we send it to file descriptor 3 instead of 1, which is what the pipe reads). Then we redirect `command2`'s output to file descriptor 4, so that it also stays out of file descriptor one – because we want file descriptor one clear for when we bring the `echo` output on file descriptor three back down into file descriptor one so that the command substitution (the backticks) can capture it.

The final bit of magic is that first `exec 4>&1` we did as a separate command – it opens file descriptor four as a copy of the external shell's stdout. Command substitution will capture whatever is written on standard out from the perspective of the commands inside it – but, since `command2`'s output is going to file descriptor four as far as the command substitution is concerned, the command substitution doesn't capture it – however, once it gets "out" of the command substitution, it is effectively still going to the script's overall file descriptor one.

(The `exec 4>&1` has to be a separate command to work with many common shells. In some shells it works if you just put it on the same line as the variable assignment, after the closing backtick of the substitution.)

(I use compound commands (`{ ... }`) in my example, but subshells (`( ... )`) would also work. The subshell will just cause a redundant forking and awaiting of a child process, since each side of a pipe and the inside of a command substitution already normally implies a fork and await of a child process, and I don't know of any shell being coded to recognize that it can skip one of those forks because it's already done or is about to do the other.)

You can look at it in a less technical and more playful way, as if the outputs of the commands are leapfrogging each other: `command1` pipes to `command2`, then the `echo`'s output jumps over `command2` so that `command2` doesn't catch it, and then `command2`'s output jumps over and out of the command substitution just as `echo` lands just in time to get captured by the substitution so that it ends up in the variable, and `command2`'s output goes on its way to the standard output, just as in a normal pipe.

Also, as I understand it, at the end of this command, `$?` will still contain the return code of the second command in the pipe, because variable assignments, command substitutions, and compound commands are all effectively transparent to the return code of the command inside them, so the return status of `command2` should get propagated out.

A caveat is that it is possible that `command1` will at some point end up using file descriptors three or four, or that `command2` or any of the later commands will use file descriptor four, so to be more hygienic, we would do:

```
exec 4>&1
exitstatus=`{ { command1 3>&-; echo $? 1>&3; } 4>&- | command2 1>&4; } 3>&1`
exec 4>&-
```

Commands inherit file descriptors from the process that launches them, so the entire second line will inherit file descriptor four, and the compound command followed by `3>&1` will inherit the file descriptor three. So the `4>&-` makes sure that the inner compound command will not inherit file descriptor four, and the `3>&-` makes sure that `command1` will not inherit file descriptor three, so command1 gets a 'cleaner', more standard environment. You could also move the inner `4>&-` next to the `3>&-`, but I figure why not just limit its scope as much as possible.

Almost no programs uses pre-opened file descriptor three and four directly, so you almost never have to worry about it, but the latter is probably best to keep in mind and use for general-purpose cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
{ mycommand --foo --bar 2>&1; ret=$?; } | tee -a some.log; (exit $ret)
```

Comment: At least on bash, $ret is not available outside of the {list}, so this doesn't work.

Comment: I like a variation of this solution where the value of $? is written to a file: `{ mycommand --foo --bar; echo $? > exit-code; } | tee some.log; ret=$(cat exit-code)`. Yes, it's convoluted to write to a temp file, but it's POSIX-friendly, unlike pipefail which is a bashism and also doesn't work in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

[KornShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell), *all* in one line:

```
foo; RET_VAL=$?; if test ${RET_VAL} != 0;then echo $RET_VAL; echo Error occurred!>/tmp/out.err;exit 2;fi |tee >>/tmp/out.err ; if test ${RET_VAL} != 0;then exit $RET_VAL;fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a one-liner that works in `do shell script` in AppleScript, which always uses /bin/sh (emulated by zsh). This version is the only one I found that works well:

```
mycommand 2>&1 | tee -a output.log; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

or in AppleScript

```
set theResult to do shell script "mycommand 2>&1 | tee -a " & quoted form of logFilePath & "; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming Bash or Z shell (`zsh`),

```
my_command >>my_log 2>&1
```

N.B. The sequence of redirection and duplication of standard error onto standard output is significant!

I didn't realise you wanted to see the output on screen as well. This will of course direct all output to the file *my_log*.

Comment: This sends all output to my_log, but unlike tee, it does not also show up on the console.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/bin/sh
logfile="$1"
shift
exec 2>&1
exec "$@" | tee "$logfile"
```

Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: Run this with arguments "foo false" -- should return with exit code 1 (from false), but I get 0 (presumably from tee).

Comment: My bad. Have to do it the old fashioned pipe way. PIPE=/tmp/$$.pipe;
mkfifo "$PIPE";
logfile="$1";
shift;
tee "$logfile" <"$PIPE" &;
"$@" 2>&1 >"$PIPE";
status=$?;
rm "$PIPE";
exit $status

Comment: You can [edit (change)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/985931/edit) your answer. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)