# Pipe output and capture exit status in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, pipe

I want to execute a long running command in Bash, and both capture its exit status, and [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) its output.

So I do this:

```
command | tee out.txt
ST=$?
```

The problem is that the variable ST captures the exit status of `tee` and not of command. How can I solve this?

Note that command is long running and redirecting the output to a file to view it later is not a good solution for me.

Comment: [[ "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" =~ [^0\ ] ]] && echo -e "Match - error found" || echo -e "No match - all good"

This will test all the values of the array at once and give an error message if any of the pipe values returned are not zero.  This is a pretty robust generalized solution for detecting errors in a piped situation.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another

Answer (score 620, accepted):

There is an internal Bash variable called `$PIPESTATUS`; it’s an array that holds the exit status of each command in your last foreground pipeline of commands.

```
<command> | tee out.txt ; test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0
```

Or another alternative which also works with other shells (like zsh) would be to enable pipefail:

```
set -o pipefail
...
```

The first option does *not* work with `zsh` due to a little bit different syntax.

Comment: There is a good explanation with examples of PIPESTATUS AND Pipefail here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73180/7453.

Comment: Note: $PIPESTATUS[0] holds the exit status of the first command in the pipe, $PIPESTATUS[1] the exit status of the second command, and so on.

Comment: Of course, we have to remember that this is Bash-specific: if I were to (for example) write a script to run on BusyBox's "sh" implementation on my Android device, or on some other embedded platform using some other "sh" variant, this would not work.

Comment: This behaves oddly for me from the command line vs same in bash script:
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

    exit 22 | echo Hello ; echo $? and ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
    Hello
    22 and 0

Comment: For those concerned about the unquoted variable expansion: The exit status is always unsigned 8-bit integer [in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html), therefore there is no need to quote it. This holds under Unix generally, too, where [exit status is defined to be 8-bit explicitly](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html), and it is assumed to be unsigned even by POSIX itself, e.g. when defining its [logical negation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02_01).

Comment: `PIPESTATUS` is Bash-specific, but [there is a direct equivalent in zsh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76171/50602). In other shells, including POSIX sh, you have to come up with a work-around.

Comment: If this happens, it is a bug in your Bash, @user3183018. That Bash version is rather old, about 2010 or so. Tried on several Debian machines with wide range of Bash versions (even one with Bash 3.2.39) and it always prints `Hello\n0 and 22`.

Comment: You can also use `exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}`.

Comment: This solution always returns exit code 127 if the first command does not return exit code 0. So it does not return the original exit code.

Comment: @jakobr This should not happen, maybe you're using a old/buggy version of Bash, or the command?

Comment: Unfortunatly, PIPESTATUS does not work when you get the output of your command in a variable 
exit 22 | echo Hello ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} # 22
hello=$(exit 22 | echo Hello) ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} # 0

Answer (score 171):

Dumb solution: Connecting them through a named pipe (mkfifo). Then the command can be run second.

```
 mkfifo pipe
 tee out.txt < pipe &
 command > pipe
 echo $?
```

EDIT: Since I had to look this up, I'm adding the decoration to use a randomly named pipe and closing it. Also sends stdout to the named pipe. I needed multiple such structures in a single script. - LM

```
pipename="pipe-$RANDOM" ; mkfifo "$pipename" ; tee -a "$LOG_FILE" < "$pipename" &
command > "$pipename" 2>&1
echo $?
rm "$pipename"
```

Comment: This is the only answer in this question that also works for the simple **sh** Unix shell.  Thanks!

Comment: @DaveKennedy: Dumb as in "obvious, not requiring intricate knowledge of bash syntax"

Comment: While the bash answers are more elegant when you have the advantage of bash's extra capabilities, this is the more cross platform solution. It's also something that's worth thinking about in general as any time you're doing a long-running command a name pipe is often the most flexible way. It's worth noting that some systems don't have `mkfifo` and may instead require `mknod -p` if I remember right.

Comment: In case someone has a problem with `mkfifo` or `mknod -p`: in my case proper command to create pipe file was `mknod FILE_NAME p`.

Comment: `mkfifo` seems more portable https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: Thanks. It works also with Ksh (in fact Ksh emulated with Zsh).
How close properly the pipe? By a simple rm pipe?

Comment: @OlivierPirson See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648974/should-named-pipes-opened-with-mkfifo-be-closed-and-how

Answer (score 155):

using bash's `set -o pipefail` is helpful

> pipefail: the return value of a pipeline is the status of
>      the last command to exit with a non-zero status,
>      or zero if no command exited with a non-zero status

Comment: In case you don't want to modify the pipefail setting of the whole script, you can set the option only locally: `( set -o pipefail; command | tee out.txt ); ST=$?`

Comment: @Jaan This would run a subshell. If you want to avoid that, you could do `set -o pipefail` and then do the command, and immediately afterwards do `set +o pipefail` to unset the option.

Comment: Note: the question poster doesn't want a "general exit code" of the pipe, he wants the return code of 'command'. With `-o pipefail` he would know if the pipe fails, but if both 'command' and 'tee' fail, he would receive the exit code from 'tee'.

Comment: @LinusArver wouldn't that clear the exit code since it's a command that succeeds?

Answer (score 39):

There's an array that gives you the exit status of each command in a pipe.

```
$ cat x| sed 's///'
cat: x: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
0
$ cat x| sed 's///'
cat: x: No such file or directory
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}
1 0
$ touch x
$ cat x| sed 's'
sed: 1: "s": substitute pattern can not be delimited by newline or backslash
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}
0 1
```

Answer (score 32):

This solution works without using bash specific features or temporary files. Bonus: in the end the exit status is actually an exit status and not some string in a file.

Situation:

```
someprog | filter
```

you want the exit status from `someprog` and the output from `filter`.

Here is my solution:

```
((((someprog; echo $? >&3) | filter >&4) 3>&1) | (read xs; exit $xs)) 4>&1

echo $?
```

See [my answer for the same question on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70675/1170) for a detailed explanation and an alternative without subshells and some caveats.

Answer (score 24):

By combining `PIPESTATUS[0]` and the result of executing the `exit` command in a subshell, you can directly access the return value of your initial command:

`command | tee ; ( exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]} )`

Here's an example:

```
# the "false" shell built-in command returns 1
false | tee ; ( exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]} )
echo "return value: $?"
```

will give you:

`return value: 1`

Comment: Thanks, this allowed me to use the construct: ``VALUE=$(might_fail | piping)`` which won't set PIPESTATUS in the master shell but will set its errorlevel. By using: ``VALUE=$(might_fail | piping; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})`` I get want I wanted.

Comment: @vaab, that syntax looks really nice but I am confused on what 'piping' means in your context? Is that just where one would do 'tee' or whatever processing on the output of might_fail? ty!

Comment: @AnneTheAgile 'piping' in my example stands for commands from which you don't want to see the errlvl. For instance: one of or any piped combination of 'tee', 'grep', 'sed', ... It's not so uncommon that these piping commands are meant to format or extract info from a larger output or log output of the main command: you are then more interested in the errlevel of the main command (the one I've called 'might_fail' in my example) but without my construct the whole assignation returns the last piped command's errlvl which is here meaningless. Is this clearer ?

Comment: `command_might_fail | grep -v "line_pattern_to_exclude" || exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` in case not tee but grep filtering

Answer (score 13):

So I wanted to contribute an answer like lesmana's, but I think mine is perhaps a little simpler and slightly more advantageous pure-Bourne-shell solution:

```
# You want to pipe command1 through command2:
exec 4>&1
exitstatus=`{ { command1; printf $? 1>&3; } | command2 1>&4; } 3>&1`
# $exitstatus now has command1's exit status.
```

I think this is best explained from the inside out - command1 will execute and print its regular output on stdout (file descriptor 1), then once it's done, printf will execute and print icommand1's exit code on its stdout, but that stdout is redirected to file descriptor 3.

While command1 is running, its stdout is being piped to command2 (printf's output never makes it to command2 because we send it to file descriptor 3 instead of 1, which is what the pipe reads). Then we redirect command2's output to file descriptor 4, so that it also stays out of file descriptor 1 - because we want file descriptor 1 free for a little bit later, because we will bring the printf output on file descriptor 3 back down into file descriptor 1 - because that's what the command substitution (the backticks), will capture and that's what will get placed into the variable.

The final bit of magic is that first `exec 4>&1` we did as a separate command - it opens file descriptor 4 as a copy of the external shell's stdout. Command substitution will capture whatever is written on standard out from the perspective of the commands inside it - but since command2's output is going to file descriptor 4 as far as the command substitution is concerned, the command substitution doesn't capture it - however once it gets "out" of the command substitution it is effectively still going to the script's overall file descriptor 1.

(The `exec 4>&1` has to be a separate command because many common shells don't like it when you try to write to a file descriptor inside a command substitution, that is opened in the "external" command that is using the substitution. So this is the simplest portable way to do it.)

You can look at it in a less technical and more playful way, as if the outputs of the commands are leapfrogging each other: command1 pipes to command2, then the printf's output jumps over command 2 so that command2 doesn't catch it, and then command 2's output jumps over and out of the command substitution just as printf lands just in time to get captured by the substitution so that it ends up in the variable, and command2's output goes on its merry way being written to the standard output, just as in a normal pipe.

Also, as I understand it, `$?` will still contain the return code of the second command in the pipe, because variable assignments, command substitutions, and compound commands are all effectively transparent to the return code of the command inside them, so the return status of command2 should get propagated out - this, and not having to define an additional function, is why I think this might be a somewhat better solution than the one proposed by lesmana.

Per the caveats lesmana mentions, it's possible that command1 will at some point end up using file descriptors 3 or 4, so to be more robust, you would do:

```
exec 4>&1
exitstatus=`{ { command1 3>&-; printf $? 1>&3; } 4>&- | command2 1>&4; } 3>&1`
exec 4>&-
```

Note that I use compound commands in my example, but subshells (using `( )` instead of `{ }` will also work, though may perhaps be less efficient.)

Commands inherit file descriptors from the process that launches them, so the entire second line will inherit file descriptor four, and the compound command followed by `3>&1` will inherit the file descriptor three. So the `4>&-` makes sure that the inner compound command will not inherit file descriptor four, and the `3>&-` will not inherit file descriptor three, so command1 gets a 'cleaner', more standard environment. You could also move the inner `4>&-` next to the `3>&-`, but I figure why not just limit its scope as much as possible.

I'm not sure how often things use file descriptor three and four directly - I think most of the time programs use syscalls that return not-used-at-the-moment file descriptors, but sometimes code writes to file descriptor 3 directly, I guess (I could imagine a program checking a file descriptor to see if it's open, and using it if it is, or behaving differently accordingly if it's not). So the latter is probably best to keep in mind and use for general-purpose cases.

Comment: Nice explanation!

Answer (score 11):

```
(command | tee out.txt; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
```

Unlike @cODAR's answer this returns the original exit code of the first command and not only 0 for success and 127 for failure. But as @Chaoran pointed out you can just call `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`. It is important however that all is put into brackets.

Comment: I like this approach. We can also do `( set +e ; command | tee ... )` to prevent the script from exiting if `tee` fails and the outer script has `set -e`.

Comment: For that reason, `( ... exit )` is preferable to `{ ... return }` because although our child shell does inherit the `set -e` from the parent, our `set +e` does not affect the parent shell.

Answer (score 8):

Outside of bash, you can do:

```
bash -o pipefail  -c "command1 | tee output"
```

This is useful for example in ninja scripts where the shell is expected to be `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu and Debian, you can `apt-get install moreutils`.   This contains a utility called `mispipe` that returns the exit status of the first command in the pipe.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to do this in plain bash is to use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) instead of a pipeline. There are several differences, but they probably don't matter very much for your use case:

- When running a pipeline, bash waits until all processes complete.
- Sending Ctrl-C to bash makes it kill all the processes of a pipeline, not just the main one.
- The `pipefail` option and the `PIPESTATUS` variable are irrelevant to process substitution.
- Possibly more

With process substitution, bash just starts the process and forgets about it, it's not even visible in `jobs`.

Mentioned differences aside, `consumer < <(producer)` and `producer | consumer` are essentially equivalent.

If you want to flip which one is the "main" process, you just flip the commands and the direction of the substitution to `producer > >(consumer)`. In your case:

```
command > >(tee out.txt)
```

Example:

```
$ { echo "hello world"; false; } > >(tee out.txt)
hello world
$ echo $?
1
$ cat out.txt
hello world

$ echo "hello world" > >(tee out.txt)
hello world
$ echo $?
0
$ cat out.txt
hello world
```

As I said, there are differences from the pipe expression. The process may never stop running, unless it is sensitive to the pipe closing. In particular, it may keep writing things to your stdout, which may be confusing.

Comment: This is my preferred solution.

Answer (score 3):

PIPESTATUS[@] must be copied to an array immediately after the pipe command returns.
*Any* reads of PIPESTATUS[@] will erase the contents. 
Copy it to another array if you plan on checking the status of all pipe commands.
"$?" is the same value as the last element of "${PIPESTATUS[@]}",
and reading it seems to destroy "${PIPESTATUS[@]}", but I haven't absolutely verified this.

```
declare -a PSA  
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3  
PSA=( "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" )
```

This will not work if the pipe is in a sub-shell. For a solution to that problem,
see [bash pipestatus in backticked command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776100/bash-pipestatus-in-backticked-command)

Answer (score 2):

Base on @brian-s-wilson 's answer; this bash helper function:

```
pipestatus() {
  local S=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")

  if test -n "$*"
  then test "$*" = "${S[*]}"
  else ! [[ "${S[@]}" =~ [^0\ ] ]]
  fi
}
```

used thus:

1: get_bad_things must succeed, but it should produce no output; but we want to see output that it does produce

```
get_bad_things | grep '^'
pipeinfo 0 1 || return
```

2: all pipeline must succeed

```
thing | something -q | thingy
pipeinfo || return
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure shell solution:

```
% rm -f error.flag; echo hello world \
| (cat || echo "First command failed: $?" >> error.flag) \
| (cat || echo "Second command failed: $?" >> error.flag) \
| (cat || echo "Third command failed: $?" >> error.flag) \
; test -s error.flag  && (echo Some command failed: ; cat error.flag)
hello world
```

And now with the second `cat` replaced by `false`:

```
% rm -f error.flag; echo hello world \
| (cat || echo "First command failed: $?" >> error.flag) \
| (false || echo "Second command failed: $?" >> error.flag) \
| (cat || echo "Third command failed: $?" >> error.flag) \
; test -s error.flag  && (echo Some command failed: ; cat error.flag)
Some command failed:
Second command failed: 1
First command failed: 141
```

Please note the first cat fails as well, because it's stdout gets closed on it. The order of the failed commands in the log is correct in this example, but don't rely on it.

This method allows for capturing stdout and stderr for the individual commands so you can then dump that as well into a log file if an error occurs, or just delete it if no error (like the output of dd).

Answer (score 1):

It may sometimes be simpler and clearer to use an external command, rather than digging into the details of bash. [pipeline](http://www.skarnet.org/software/execline/pipeline.html), from the minimal process scripting language [execline](http://www.skarnet.org/software/execline/), exits with the return code of the second command*, just like a `sh` pipeline does, but unlike `sh`, it allows reversing the direction of the pipe, so that we can capture the return code of the producer process (the below is all on the `sh` command line, but with `execline` installed):

```
$ # using the full execline grammar with the execlineb parser:
$ execlineb -c 'pipeline { echo "hello world" } tee out.txt'
hello world
$ cat out.txt
hello world

$ # for these simple examples, one can forego the parser and just use "" as a separator
$ # traditional order
$ pipeline echo "hello world" "" tee out.txt 
hello world

$ # "write" order (second command writes rather than reads)
$ pipeline -w tee out.txt "" echo "hello world"
hello world

$ # pipeline execs into the second command, so that's the RC we get
$ pipeline -w tee out.txt "" false; echo $?
1

$ pipeline -w tee out.txt "" true; echo $?
0

$ # output and exit status
$ pipeline -w tee out.txt "" sh -c "echo 'hello world'; exit 42"; echo "RC: $?"
hello world
RC: 42
$ cat out.txt
hello world
```

Using `pipeline` has the same differences to native bash pipelines as the bash process substitution used in answer [#43972501](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43972501/260122).

* Actually `pipeline` doesn't exit at all unless there is an error. It executes into the second command, so it's the second command that does the returning.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `stderr`?  Like so:

```
(
     # Our long-running process that exits abnormally
    ( for i in {1..100} ; do echo ploop ; sleep 0.5 ; done ; exit 5 )
    echo $? 1>&2 # We pass the exit status of our long-running process to stderr (fd 2).
) | tee ploop.out
```

So `ploop.out` receives the `stdout`.  `stderr` receives the exit status of the long running process.  This has the benefit of being completely POSIX-compatible.

(Well, with the exception of the range expression in the example long-running process, but that's not really relevant.)

Here's what this looks like:

```
...
ploop
ploop
ploop
ploop
ploop
ploop
ploop
ploop
ploop
ploop
5
```

Note that the return code `5` does not get output to the file `ploop.out`.