# Shell Script won't run from NodeJS because it has "set -o pipefail"

Tags: node.js, bash, zsh

My script keeps dying with the error

```
./script.sh: 2: set: Illegal option -o pipefail
```

This is how I call it

```
var cp = require("child_process");
cp.exec("script.sh", function(){ console.log(...arguments); });
```

This is the script

```
set -e
set -o pipefail

ls .
...
```

I put these lines in the script because they make it die if there is an error instead of continuing.  I don't know what they mean and was hoping someone could help.

Comment: Can you send your nodejs app (or a standalone snippet that works) for me to try it locally?

Comment: That error message looks like it's coming from dash, which doesn't have a `pipefail` option. You need to run the script under bash or zsh. Check its shebang line. See ["Linux/Ubuntu set: Illegal option -o pipefail"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055549/linux-ubuntu-set-illegal-option-o-pipefail) or possibly ["equivalent of pipefail in dash shell"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757039/equivalent-of-pipefail-in-dash-shell).

Comment: @GordonDavisson You did great!  Adding a shebang fixed it! Do you want to write it as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: @user3413723 Since it's pretty close to the other question, and Mike's answer there is pretty much the solution that did it (just from a different starting point), I'll mark it as a duplicate and you should give Mike an upcode.