# How to process output line by line AND save the return status?

Tags: bash

First, hello to stackoverflow community. I have learnt a lot thank to very clear questions and professional replies. I never needed to ask question because there is always someone who has asked the same question before.

But not today. I haven't found any solution to my problem, and I beg for your help.
I need to process the output of a function line by line in order to update a log online. I am working with `bash`.

The following block works pretty well:

```
convertor some parameters | while read line
do
    if [ "${line:0:14}" != "[informations]" ]
    then
        update_online_log "${line}"
    fi
done
```

But `convertor` may exit with different status. And I need to know what was the exit status. The code below doesn't work as it gives me the exit status of the last executed command (`update_online_log`).

```
convertor some parameters | while read line
do
    if [ "${line:0:14}" != "[informations]" ]
    then
        update_online_log "${line}"
    fi
done
exit_status=$?
```

The code below should work (I haven't tried it yet):

```
convertor some parameters > out.txt
exit_status=$?
while read line
do
    if [ "${line:0:14}" != "[informations]" ]
    then
        update_online_log "${line}"
    fi
done < out.txt
rm out.txt
```

But if I use this, the online log will be updated at the end of the conversion. Conversion may be a very long process, and I want to keep users updated while the conversion is in progress.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1221833/215924

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thank you very much it is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PIPESTATUS` array may be helpful for you: it saves the exit statuses of each component of the previous pipeline:

```
$ (echo a; exit 42) | (cat; echo b; exit 21) | (cat; echo c; exit 3) | { cat; echo hello; }
a
b
c
hello
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[*]}"
42 21 3 0
```

That array is pretty fragile, so if you want to do stuff with it, immediately save it to another array:

```
$ (echo a; exit 42) | ... as above
$ ps=( "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" )
$ for i in "${!ps[@]}"; do echo "$i  ${ps[$i]}"; done
0  42
1  21
2  3
3  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `set -o pipefail` at the top of the script. From the documentation:

> the return value of a pipeline is the status of
>                             the last command to exit with a non-zero status,
>                             or zero if no command exited with a non-zero status

That means it's zero if all commands succeed and non-zero if any command fails.

Just check the exit status after the `done`, that should work. Test it with

```
convertor some parameters | false | while read line
...
```

No line should be processed and the exit code should be `1`.

Answer (score 0):

As a POSIX-compliant solution, and to show that your approach was close to working, you can use a named pipe instead of a regular file.

```
mkfifo out.txt
while read line; do
    if [[ $line != \[informations\]* ]]; then
        update_online_log "$line"
    fi
done < out.txt &

convertor some parameters > out.txt

rm out.txt
```

This code creates the named pipe, then runs the loop that consumes it in the background. It will block waiting for data from `converter`. Once `converter` exits (and you can get its exit code at that time), `out.txt` will be closed, the `while` loop process will exit, and you can remove the named pipe.