# Bash: reference the first part of '||' or pipe command

Tags: bash, pipe

Is a command somehow saved/possible to be referenced to in a pipe?
 For example:

`cd /tmp/non_existing_dir || echo "could not execute $PREVIOUS_PIPE_CMD`

without pre-saving the original command. `$PREVIOUS_PIPE_CMD` is an example variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221833/bash-pipe-output-and-capture-exit-status

Comment: But, It is not pipe. It is `||` control operator. Is it typo?

Comment: @sat  thanks, I don't know why I said that this is a pipe. Will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Piping works by black-boxing and relaying IO streams and statuses. There is no way for the command that has been piped into to know the downstream history without relaying it/saving it and passing it around.

Also: your example is not using piping, it is using `||`, which is `OR`, not a pipe.

```
cd /tmp/non_existing_dir || echo "could not execute $PREVIOUS_PIPE_CMD"
```

is the same as

```
if [[ $(cd foo) ]]; then
  :
else
  echo "could not execute $PREVIOUS_PIPE_CMD
fi
```

Given your example you would want:

```
tmpdir="/tmp/non_existing_dir"
cd ${tmpdir} 2>/dev/null || echo "could not cd into '${tmpdir}'"
```