# How to redirect output to stdout & file and getting return value of first command in pipe?

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/418899/4103007), and is mostly suitable for what I'm looking for, except that it's missing how to get the return value from the first command. Doing this will give the return value code for the command `tee`, which is not what I'm looking for.

Example:

```
ls /path/to/dir 2>&1 | tee foo.txt
echo $?
```

Where `$?` will show the code of `ls`.

How do I achieve the above?

EDIT: Thanks for the answer, [Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w)! However, I should've been more specific: I need bash *prompt* (not script) to return it; since returns only work from a script or a function perspective, my best bet is to wrap this around a function, then. Is this right?

EDIT 2: Here's what I was looking for:

`fn() {
    ls | tee foo.txt return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
    return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
}
fn`

Comment: You want the $PIPESTATUS array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash: pipe output AND capture exit status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221833/bash-pipe-output-and-capture-exit-status)

Comment: Couldn't find that question. I'm sorry, I should've used better wording when searching through SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an environment variable [`PIPESTATUS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-PIPESTATUS):

> An array variable (see [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays)) containing a list of exit status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).

So the exit status of `ls` will be in `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`.

Comment: This is a good start! However, I apologize as I should've been more specific: I need bash to return it; since returns only work from a script or a function perspective, my best bet is to wrap this around a function, then. Is this right?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Does `return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` not work? Or what do you mean with "return it"?

Comment: This is what I was looking for to be used in a bash prompt:

```fn() {  
    ls | tee foo.txt  
    return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}  
}  
fn```



Your answer has helped me a lot! Thank you