# Check return status of psql command in unix shell scripting

Tags: postgresql, shell

I am using psql command to connect and issue a query on postgreSQL database. Can anybody let me know how to check the return status of the executed query in shell script.

I have used `echo $?` command to check the status but it always returning zero.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`psql` return code [is documented as](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.18.7):

> EXIT STATUS
>          psql returns 0 to the shell if it finished normally, 1 if a fatal error
>          of its own occurs (e.g. out of memory, file not found), 2 if the
>          connection to the server went bad and the session was not interactive,
>          and 3 if an error occurred in a script and the variable ON_ERROR_STOP
>          was set.

You probably just want to use ON_ERROR_STOP.

**Failure getting tested and reported to the shell:**

```
$ psql -d test -v "ON_ERROR_STOP=1" <<EOF
select error;
select 'OK';
EOF

ERROR:  column "error" does not exist
LINE 1: select error;

$ echo $?
3
```

**Failure getting ignored and not reported to the shell:**

```
$ psql -d test  <<EOF
select error;
select 'OK';
EOF
ERROR:  column "error" does not exist
LINE 1: select error;
               ^
 ?column? 
----------
 OK
(1 row)

$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be triggered with permission errors. I had a command exit with status 0

Comment: @raphael: might be a bug, do you have a test case to share?

Comment: Are there system tables that a non-super user wouldn't be able to access?

Comment: @raphael: `pg_catalog.pg_authid`

Comment: ah.... I think the issue is I was pipeing between two commands and the first one was failing. `psql -v "ON_ERROR_STOP=1" -c "\COPY pg_catalog.pg_authid TO STDOUT;" | cat` produces `ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_authid`, but an exit code of 0. Going to use this going forward https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221833/pipe-output-and-capture-exit-status-in-bash

Comment: @raphael: see `set -o pipefail` in bash to fail the pipeline on error

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/22833/postgres-non-zero-exit-code-when-executing-a-sql-file), you can also add this line at the top of your SQL file/script:

```
\set ON_ERROR_STOP true
```