# How to check if .sql script execution succeeded?

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

I'm loading an exported database with the below commands:

```
psql -c 'drop database database1'
psql -c 'create database database1'
psql database1 < script.sql
```

Now I'm trying to check if the final command succeeded:

```
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "OK."
else
    echo "Not OK."
fi
```

This *always* outputs "OK." the Exit code is always 0, even if `script.sql` completes with errors:

```
psql database1 < script.sql
ERROR: constraint "test_id" for relation "test" already exists
echo $?
0
```

How can I confirm the sql import succeeded?

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480381/postgres-sql-fail-on-script-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check return status of psql command in unix shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072245/check-return-status-of-psql-command-in-unix-shell-scripting) In short: Instead try: `psql -v "ON_ERROR_STOP=1" database1 < script.sql` and test the results of that. You should get return code `3`. See the duplicate I flagged for more info.

Comment: Looks like it does not properly set the return code. Either parse the output text or configure it to return with a proper error code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do check if the command throws an error like this:

```
psql database1 < script.sql || echo 'error occurred'
```

The double pipe `||` means "Do the left part and if error do the right part of the pipes".

Hope it helps!