# Filter output of a process with `grep` while keeping the return value

Tags: python, bash, ssh, grep, return-value

I think this is not a Python question but in order to provide the context I'll tell, what exactly I'm doing.

I run a command on a remote machine using `ssh -t <host> <command>` like this:

```
if os.system('ssh -t some_machine [ -d /some/directory ]') != 0:
    do_something()
```

(note: `[ -d /some/directory ]` is only an example. Could be replaced by any command which returns 0 in case everything went fine)

Unfortunately `ssh` prints "Connection to some_machine close." every time I run it.

Stupidly I tried to run `ssh -t some_machine <command> | grep -v "Connection"` but this returns the result of `grep` of course.

So in short: In Python I'd like to run a process via `ssh` and evaluate it's return value while filtering away some unwanted output.

**Edit:** [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221833/bash-pipe-output-and-capture-exit-status) suggests s.th. like

```
<command> | grep -v "bla"; return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

Indeed this might be an approach but it seems to work with `bash` only. At least with `zsh` `PIPESTATUS` seems to be not defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash: pipe output AND capture exit status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221833/bash-pipe-output-and-capture-exit-status)

Comment: ssh is printing that message on stderr so you can pipe it to null with `2>/dev/null`. With the `-t` option that you're using ssh should redirect the remote command's stderr to stdout so it shouldn't be lost.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing right now. The problem is that this way you also loose diagnostic output in case something went wrong with the `ssh` connection itself..

Answer (score 2):

Use `subprocess`, and connect the two commands in Python rather than a shell pipeline.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call
p1 = Popen(["ssh", "-t", "some_machine", "test", "-d", "/some/directory"],
           stdout=PIPE)
if call(["grep", "-v", "Connection"], stdin=p1.stdout) != 0:
    # use p1.returncode for the exit status of ssh
    do_something()
```

Taking this a step further, try to avoid running external programs when unnecessary. You can examine the output of `ssh` directly in Python without using `grep`; for example, using the `re` library to examine the data read from `p1.stdout` yourself. You can also use a library like Paramiko to connect to the remote host instead of shelling out to run `ssh`.