# Makefile logging which stops at first error and display the error

Tags: c, logging, makefile

I am looking for a way to log compilation errors within a makefile but here is my problem:

the line without log function is as follows:

```
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.obj: $(SRC_PATH_ASW)/%.c
    @echo -Compiling $<:
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_ASW) $(INCLUDE_ASW_AUTO) $(INCLUDE_BSW) -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

I tried to  redirect stderr and/or stdout in a log file using the following command

```
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.obj: $(SRC_PATH_ASW)/%.c
    @echo -Compiling $<:
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_ASW) $(INCLUDE_ASW_AUTO) $(INCLUDE_BSW) -c $< $(CFLAGS)  > $@.log
```

This solution won't display the message to the terminal but only within the log file. (i tried all possible kind of redirection without success)

I also tried with tee but the problem is different, in fact the makefile won't stop at first error since the tee command return code will always be successful.

```
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.obj: $(SRC_PATH_ASW)/%.c
    @echo -Compiling $<:
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_ASW) $(INCLUDE_ASW_AUTO) $(INCLUDE_BSW) -c $< $(CFLAGS) | tee $@.log
```

What I would like if possible is to be able to log compilation result into a file as well as disply it but that the makefile stops at first compilation error and does not continue with other files compilation.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: `man tee` is a great start

Comment: Duplicate: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221833/pipe-output-and-capture-exit-status-in-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set -o pipefail` or `PIPESTATUS[0]`

```
set -o pipefail; $(CC) ... | tee file.log
```

will return an error if the `$(CC) ...` or `tee...` commands fail.   Alternatively if you just do

```
$(CC) ... | tee file.log
```

Then `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` will be the error code of the first command (`$(CC)...`) (you can tack an `exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` at the end of the line for example.

Answer (score 0):

I've often wanted to do this too and the solution I came up with was to create this short shell script and alias make to run that instead.

```
#!/bin/sh

make $* | tee make.log
```