# Getting the exit status of a nested command inside a redirect attached to tee

Tags: linux, bash, awk, tee, pipestatus

I have this command:

```
coverage report | tee >(grep TOTAL | awk '{exit (int($4) >= 75)?0:1}') && (exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
```

which reports the code coverage and then prints the output to `stdout` and redirects that same output to a grep + awk, which basically checks whether the code coverage covers less or more than `75`. Finally, there is an `exit` in a subshell, which I pretend to use in my CI/CD pipeline.

The problem is that my CI/CD always completes successfully, which shouldn't happen as the code coverage is less than 75% in my tests. That means that the `PIEPSTATUS` isn't returning what I'm expecting it to return (awk's `exit` code).

Where is the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you running `exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` inside a subshell `(...)`?

Comment: Because I want to set the exit code, so that the CI/CD will act upon it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get exit status of process that's piped to another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14270/56041), [Pipe output and capture exit status in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1221833/608639), etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exit status of

```
command | tee >(...)
```

will be the exit status of `tee`, regardless of what happens inside the [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) `>(...)`.  That's the reason your code is not working.

You can achieve your goal without having to use process substitution, like this:

```
coverage report | awk '{print} /TOTAL/ { pcnt=$4 } END {exit (int(pcnt) >= 75) ? 0 : 1}')
```

- `{print}` prints all the lines
- `/TOTAL/ ...` grabs the percentage and saves it in `pcnt`
- `END ...` exits code based on `pcnt`

This will not only print all the lines emitted by `coverage report`, it would also make sure that the exit code of pipeline reflects the coverage percentage logic.

Comment: Yes, this totally simplifies my code and works exactly as expected. Thank you!