# bash: redirect (and append) stdout and stderr to file and terminal and get proper exit status

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, tee

To redirect (and append) stdout and stderr to a file, while also displaying it on the terminal, I do this:

```
command 2>&1 | tee -a file.txt
```

However, is there another way to do this such that I get an accurate value for the exit status?

That is, if I test `$?`, I want to see the exit status of `command`, not the exit status of `tee`.

I know that I can use `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` here instead of `$?`, but I am looking for another solution that would not involve having to check `PIPESTATUS`.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `PIPESTATUS`?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985876/tee-and-exit-status, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221833/bash-tee-output-and-capture-exit-status

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Perhaps you could put the exit value from PIPESTATUS into `$?`

```
command 2>&1 | tee -a file.txt ; ( exit ${PIPESTATUS} )
```

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility, with some `bash` flavours, is to turn on the `pipefail` option:

> pipefail
>
> If  set,  the  return  value of a pipeline is
>   the value of the last (rightmost)
>   command to exit with a non-zero
>    status, or zero if all commands in the
>   pipeline exit successfully.  This
>   option is disabled by default.

```
set -o pipefail
...
command 2>&1 | tee -a file.txt || echo "Command (or tee?) failed with status $?"
```

This having been said, the only way of achieving `PIPESTATUS` functionality portably (e.g. so it'd also work with POSIX `sh`) is a bit convoluted, i.e. it requires *a temp file* to propagate a pipe exit status back to the parent shell process:

```
{ command 2>&1 ; echo $? >"/tmp/~pipestatus.$$" ; } | tee -a file.txt
if [ "`cat \"/tmp/~pipestatus.$$\"`" -ne 0 ] ; then
  ...
fi
```

or, encapsulating for reuse:

```
log2file() {
  LOGFILE="$1" ; shift
  { "$@" 2>&1 ; echo $? >"/tmp/~pipestatus.$$" ; } | tee -a "$LOGFILE"
  MYPIPESTATUS="`cat \"/tmp/~pipestatus.$$\"`"
  rm -f "/tmp/~pipestatus.$$"
  return $MYPIPESTATUS
}

log2file file.txt command param1 "param 2" || echo "Command failed with status $?"
```

or, more generically perhaps:

```
save_pipe_status() {
  STATUS_ID="$1" ; shift
  "$@"
  echo $? >"/tmp/~pipestatus.$$.$STATUS_ID"
}

get_pipe_status() {
  STATUS_ID="$1" ; shift
  return `cat "/tmp/~pipestatus.$$.$STATUS_ID"`
}

save_pipe_status my_command_id ./command param1 "param 2" | tee -a file.txt
get_pipe_status my_command_id || echo "Command failed with status $?"

...

rm -f "/tmp/~pipestatus.$$."* # do this in a trap handler, too, to be really clean
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an arcane POSIX way of doing this:

```
exec 4>&1; R=$({ { command1; echo $? >&3 ; } | { command2 >&4; } } 3>&1); exec 4>&-
```

It will set the variable `R` to the return value of `command1`, and pipe output of `command1` to `command2`, whose output is redirected to the output of parent shell.

Answer (score 4):

Use process substitution:

```
command > >( tee -a "$logfile" ) 2>&1
```

tee runs in a subshell so $? holds the exit status of *command*.